# Using the earliest date of a partition to determine what other dates belong to that partition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Assume this is my table:

```
ID  DATE
--------------
1   2018-11-12 
2   2018-11-13
3   2018-11-14
4   2018-11-15
5   2018-11-16
6   2019-03-05
7   2019-05-07
8   2019-05-08
9   2019-05-08
```

I need to have partitions be determined by the first date in the partition. Where, any date that is within 2 days of the first date, belongs in the same partition.

The table would end up looking like this if each partition was ranked

```
PARTITION ID  DATE
------------------------
1         1   2018-11-12 
1         2   2018-11-13
1         3   2018-11-14
2         4   2018-11-15
2         5   2018-11-16
3         6   2019-03-05
4         7   2019-05-07
4         8   2019-05-08
4         9   2019-05-08
```

I've tried using datediff with lag to compare to the previous date but that would allow a partition to be inappropriately sized based on spacing, for example all of these dates would be included in the same partition:

```
ID  DATE
--------------
1   2018-11-12 
2   2018-11-14
3   2018-11-16
4   2018-11-18
3   2018-11-20
4   2018-11-22
```

Previous flawed attempt:

Mark when a date is more than 2 days past the previous date:

```
(case when datediff(day, lag(event_time, 1) over (partition by user_id, stage order by event_time), event_time) > 2 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: You could also try writing a simple JavaScript UDTF in Snowflake, they are very powerful and can provide arbitrary functionality of this kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a recursive CTE for this, so the operation is expensive.

```
with t as (
      -- add an incrementing column with no gaps
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, date, date as mindate, seqnum
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.id, t.date,
             (case when t.date <= dateadd(day, 2, cte.mindate)
                   then cte.mindate else t.date
              end) as mindate,
             t.seqnum
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
    )
select cte.*, dense_rank() over (partition by mindate) as partition_num
from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gordon, it seems to be working!: https://imgur.com/a/W7WxHFn.



However,  since I'm doing this recursion by iterating through row numbers for the entire data set, it far exceeds the recursion limit of 100. 


Is there a way to work around this recursion limit based on the data structure I'm working with? Would breaking the seqnum into smaller partitions than the entirety of the data set be an approach? I know some languages have an option(recursionmax) but I couldn't find anything regarding a similar command in snowflake.

Comment: @geoff . . . I don't know how to do that.  A limit of 100 seems really low as a recursion limit.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help! The solution definitely works but may be unviable for the size of the data set. Just read in documentation that I have to contact snowflake customer support so I'll work with them to up the limit and see how viable performance is.

Comment: @geoff . . . It might be possible to insert additional breaks in the data by looking for lags of greater than 2 days.  Then the recursion would only be inside those groups.  I'm not sure though if that will fix the problem over all your data.